# No todas las rutas de acceso devuelven un codigo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Tengo un error en esa función utilizando arraylist]

No todas las rutas de acceso devuelven un valor,como lo puedo solucionar..
muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola Javier, te sugiero revisar [ask] para que modifiques tu pregunta, acostumbra agregar el código como texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a tu pregunta el problema es que tu metodo por cualquiera de los flujos de ejecucion que tome, debe devolver un objeto de tipo EMPLEADO dado que la cabecera donde esta siendo definido asi lo dice, pero al ver el codigo del metodo veo que solo estas indicando si esta o no empleado por lo que una solucion es cambiar el tipo de retorno de EMPLEADO a void asi:

```
public void BuscarEmpleado(int leg)
```

o al final del metodo, despues del ciclo foreach escribas:

```
return null;
```